remove unchanged values in pandas dataframe time series column
I want to remove recurring, unchanged values in a specific column in pandas dataframe only if they occurred after each other (handled separate by group), in other words, keep reduandant values if it didn't appers after each other.
The specific column (in my case, the value column). The group is node.
I got it to run with loops. But loops are very slow in python.
Is there a way to achieve the same in pandas without loops?
Table sorted by time ASC:



time
node
value
comment (not in df)




2024-05-07 13:39:31.315437
ns=4;i=6
NaN
ok


2024-05-07 13:39:31.327564
ns=4;i=7
5,514E+09
ok


2024-05-07 13:39:31.328585
ns=4;i=8
1
ok


2024-05-07 13:39:31.425523
ns=4;i=9
33
ok


2024-05-07 13:39:31.561920
ns=4;i=10
False
ok


...
...
...



2024-05-07 14:30:31.425454
ns=4;i=9
33
remove


...
...
...



2024-05-07 15:20:45.445578
ns=4;i=9
34
ok


...
...
...



2024-05-07 18:24:34.142277
ns=4;i=10
33
ok


2024-05-07 18:24:40.245277
ns=4;i=9
33
ok


2024-05-07 18:24:45.845477
ns=4;i=9
33
remove



node_values = {}
rows_to_delete = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['node'] in node_values and node_values[row['node']] == row['value']:
        rows_to_delete.append(index)
    node_values[row['node']] = row['value']
df = df.drop(index=rows_to_delete)

Example before:



time
node
value




2024-05-07 13:39:31.315437
ns=4;i=6
NaN


2024-05-07 13:39:31.327564
ns=4;i=7
5,514E+09


2024-05-07 13:39:31.328585
ns=4;i=8
1


2024-05-07 13:39:31.425523
ns=4;i=9
33


2024-05-07 13:39:31.561920
ns=4;i=10
False


2024-05-07 13:39:31.625523
ns=4;i=9
33


2024-05-07 13:39:31.725523
ns=4;i=9
34


2024-05-07 13:39:31.825523
ns=4;i=50
34


2024-05-07 13:39:31.925523
ns=4;i=9
34


2024-05-07 13:39:32.125523
ns=4;i=9
33


2024-05-07 13:39:31.425523
ns=4;i=100
True



after:



time
node
value




2024-05-07 13:39:31.315437
ns=4;i=6
NaN


2024-05-07 13:39:31.327564
ns=4;i=7
5,514E+09


2024-05-07 13:39:31.328585
ns=4;i=8
1


2024-05-07 13:39:31.425523
ns=4;i=9
33


2024-05-07 13:39:31.561920
ns=4;i=10
False


2024-05-07 13:39:31.725523
ns=4;i=9
34


2024-05-07 13:39:31.825523
ns=4;i=50
34


2024-05-07 13:39:32.125523
ns=4;i=9
33


2024-05-07 13:39:33.225523
ns=4;i=100
True




you can try vectorization using numpy or drop duplicate in pandas

Sorry, my example was not clear. I've edited it. The same value should be allowed again, but not one after the other...

i answerd your question based on your new update , i only conisder the column node

You can filter out the rows where they are the same as the previous one, like this:
filter= (df['node'] != df['node'].shift())

and only pick data the satisfaction the condition
filtered_df = df[filter]

Update
Based on your comments, you want to remove nodes which values (in value column ) are the same  , you can try below code to do so.
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

filter_= df.groupby('node')['value'].shift() == df['value']

filtered_df = df[~filter_]

print(filtered_df)

Note: this code will remove the row after a False Value
if you have value False in column value the row after it will be removed.

Thanks for your answer.
But unfortunately this is not equivalent to my loop variant and doesn't work either.
In principle, the task is:      -     go through each value       -     delete row if: last value with the same node is the same

@Michael can you provide input and output example please

Alternatively the answer code can be given in one line filtered_df = df[df.groupby('node')['value'].shift().ne(df['value'])]

Nice! Thanks. The loop solution and your example give me an equal output and is much faster! :)

@Michael happy to help Michael keep up the good work.
